# Mupen64 is installed, but doesn't show up in the Dash

Tags: unity, unity-2d, unity-dash

My [Mupen64](http://mupen64.emulation64.com/) installation is nowhere to be found in unity and unity2d as well... 
It works if I open it from terminal, but the gui is gone!

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I see that after one month, you still not get good answer.
So I try my "poor" answer.

I had the exact same problem than you.
**After installing Oneiric and install Mupen64**, now no more problem, my Mupen64 icon is back in the Unity Dash.